# Refreshing FlatList with remote information

Tags: react-native, refresh, react-native-flatlist

My React Native app uses a flatList to display an array of information. I am currently programming the pull to refresh method that the flatList component supports however I would like to know if there is any standard practice that allows me to first check if there has been any modification in the database since my last refresh and only if there has been then I would do a new request to fetch the info. I am afraid that if I don't have these kind of checking, the user will make a lot of useless requests and spend unnecessary data.

Comment: Depends on where your database is, you could likely look into caching db results to reduce load but from an architectural point of view it probably isn't the best practice to put the sort of check you're talking about between the user and the data. Caching results is likely more of the standard practice to reduce load.

Comment: This is such small optimization (some bytes of serialized data over the network?) for such a high cost -- trying to figure out if any of the resources that the user can see have updated over the time since they were last fetched. I imagine you could write middleware to add an updatedAt field to all docs in the db and have your client request only docs updated since the last fetch, then have the api only return those docs, and have logic in the client to map the partial fetch as an update onto your state.